# iOS 5 viewWillAppear not being called when popping a NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am learning to develop iPhone applications using iOS 5.

I am trying to create a contact list of sorts (to learn about Core Data).

I have a `UITableView` embedded in a `UINavigationController` (I have done this through Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller).

At the end of my `saveContact` action I have the line:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To move from the contact creation form to the UITableView which lists all the contacts. The code that fetches the contacts is in `viewWillAppear`.

Problem is that when I pop the contact creation form the new contact does not show on the list.

I have found in Apple's documentation that I should add the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to my `UITableViewController`, but no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [`navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method of the `UINavigationController` protocol in your `UITableViewController` and set the delegate of the navigation controller the table view controller. In you implementation of the method, check if the view that will be shown is equal to your view, and if it is then fetch the results.

If you really want to integrate Core Data with a table view, I would recommend looking into [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It simplifies handling updates to the backing data store, so if you later added background syncing functionality, the background thread could continuously update the store, and the NSFetchedResultsController could then handle updating the table for you. It would also make your current example easier, as all you'd have to do is send `save:` to Core Data and then the results controller would start updating your table, without using a `viewWillAppear:` method

Comment: How do I set the delegate  of the navigation controller?

Comment: `delegate` is a property of the UiNavigationController class, so in the `viewDidLoad` method of your table view controller, set the table view controller as the delegate of the navigation controller ( self.navigationController.delegate = self).

Comment: It didn't work. Here is a pastie of my code: http://pastie.org/3209337 and http://pastie.org/3209343. Could you have a look at it and perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: I overlooked that you were using a UITableView. Table views will not change unless explicitly told to. The easiest way is with `reloadData`, but this can be slow for large tables and makes the entire table reload. The better way is to compare the changes, and update just those cells. NSFetchedResultsController makes this easier, giving delegate methods for insert, remove and update sets. I also pulled out your calls to viewWillAppear, as that can cause problems in UIKit. Here's the changes: https://gist.github.com/d83a3eb6fdfa0d285955/7399b755f59f87ed3711e4588bc9cb56ec8a55e0

Comment: It worked. Thank you, and I mean a lot. I've been looking at this all afternoon.

Comment: I will look at `NSFetchedResultsController`, but sometime later. I have downloaded some demos using it (and I even made an attempt to use it here), but no results were being displayed what so ever.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a tough nut to crack, and it can be a royal pain if trying to target multiple versions of iOS (the list in the docs does not include all of the bugs). But once it's working, it makes background updating of entries much easier.