# Coredata not working while popping the view controllers

Tags: iphone, core-data, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 viewcontrollers (say A & B) ... I have some records in A now I want to edit the data in the core data.... For that I push the navigation controller to B.. There I edit the data in core data.. Itz working fine.. This the code I use for editing..

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CamImage" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Set the predicate -- much like a WHERE statement in a SQL database
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", xapp.patientName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // Set the sorting -- mandatory, even if you're fetching a single record/object
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    sortDescriptors = nil;
    NSError *error;
    // Request the data -- NOTE, this assumes only one match, that
    // yourIdentifyingQualifier is unique. It just grabs the first object in the array.
    CamImage *event = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];

    [event setMedicineImage:butImage];
    [event setMedicineName:text.text];
    [event setQuantity:[jst objectAtIndex:0]];
    [event setUnit:[jst objectAtIndex:1]];
    [event setMeal:meal];
     request = nil;

    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request1
                                                                                    error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    // Set self's events array to the mutable array, then clean up.
    [self setCamImage:mutableFetchResults];
    NSLog(@"AddMedicineArray:%@",camImage);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In above code I edited the data and fetched it once again..I can found the data got edited properly.. After editing I pop to B.. In the viewwillappear method I once again fetch the data.. But I find the old records only... Once I run the app again I found the edited data got fetched properly.. Here is the code in viewwillappear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    camImage=Nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CamImage" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    // Set self's events array to the mutable array, then clean up.
    [self setCamImage:mutableFetchResults];
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` is not being called, because the parent view remains in the view hierarchy the whole time. Instead, implement `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` See this question: [iOS 5 viewWillAppear not being called when popping a NavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915799/ios-5-viewwillappear-not-being-called-when-popping-a-navigationcontroller)

Comment: But my viewwillappear is called while popping...Bt my pblm is with core data...Itz not reloading properly....